# Having an issue with file path name as a part of a string in Python

Tags: python, audio, iteration

I'm going through [this example](https://github.com/mikesmales/Udacity-ML-Capstone/blob/master/Notebooks/1%20Data%20Exploration%20and%20Visualisation.ipynb) in Spyder and when I get to this part:

```
for index, row in metadata.iterrows():

file_name = os.path.join(os.path.abspath('C:/Users/myusername/Documents/projectfoldername/UrbanSound8K/audio/'),'fold'+str(row["fold"])+'/',str(row["slice_file_name"]))

data = wavfilehelper.read_file_properties(file_name)
audiodata.append(data)
```

It throws this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\myusername\Documents\projectfoldername\UrbanSound8K\Draft.py", line 28, in <module>
    data = wavfilehelper.read_file_properties(file_name)

  File "C:\Anaconda\Scripts\wavfilehelper.py", line 7, in read_file_properties
    wave_file = open(filename,"rb")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\myusername\\Documents\\projectfoldername\\UrbanSound8K\\audio\\fold5/100032-3-0-0.wav'
```

I'm new to Python so I would appreciate help with this. I'm wondering if its due to the reversed backslash after fold5? This was the original code posted by the author though. Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is at "...audio\\fold5/100032-3-0-0.wav", try removing the +'/' bit, and let path.join() do it's thing.

Comment: Does `fold5` or `100032-3-0-0.wav`, or even the full path actual exist? Since you're opening with `rb` mode it'll return `FileNotFoundError` if the exact path does not exist.  The mix of ```\\``` and `/` is not your root issue here.

Comment: Ok so that helped by removing the +\ if you want to post that as an answer. But now I'm running into a different problem. Now its giving me: "No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\myusername\\Documents\\myprojectfolder\\UrbanSound8K\\audio\\fold5\\100032-3-0-0.wav'" Even though there definitely is that file in that location lol ><